# Is the cached fb:admins property reloaded by Facebook automatically?

Tags: facebook, caching, comments

We allow users of our website to place the Facebook comments social gadget on their own public part of our website. At the time the gadget is placed we do not necessarily know their Facebook user ID. Thus at first Facebook will logically not associate any admins with the comment gadget.

When a user decides to enter his Facebook user ID later on, we add this via the fb:admins meta-tag. However, the already placed comment gadget will not directly reflect this!

I know I can update this by entering the canonical url of the comment gadget in the [Facebook Linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). Does Facebook however reload his cache of the fb:admins property. If so: when does that happen? If not: is there any way I can trigger this process automatically via an API or something?

Best,
Roel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page will be re-linted periodically, but should you wish to force a re-lint yourself, you can do this via the Graph API as specified in the [Open Graph docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/):

`POST /id={object-id or object-url}&rescrape=true`